# FB Like button shows up only once - on first load of my AngularJS view

Tags: html, angularjs, facebook-like, single-page-application, facebook-social-plugins

I am trying to place the FB like button on my single page site built on Angular JS. The like button has to be displayed on a view (different than the index.html) displayed by a controller. But the like button shows up only for the first time I load that particular view. The button do not show up if I come back after visiting another view. 
Below is the code which loads FB SDK in the controller for the view -

> (function (d, s, id) {
>       var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
>       if (d.getElementById(id)) {
>       return;
>       }
>       js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
>       js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
>       fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
>       }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

**index.html** has the following code-

> <body ng-controller="mainController">
>
> <div id="fb-root">

**myView.html**

> <div class="fb-like" data-href="mySite.com/{{ProductID}}" data-> layout="standard" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="true">

I have tried various methods like using the FB.XFBML.Parse(), removing the script tag for FB sdk and adding it in every load(with the hope that it will work like the first time), tried using the directives, placing the fb-root div in various views and now I am clueless :|

I feel the issue is with loading or refreshing the SDK on revisiting the view but I am not sure.

Will appreciate any input which will help me move forward and please let me know if you need any more info.

Thanks,
 Sam.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe I found the solution.

Set in the begining of your widget script FB = null; and remove the "if (d.getElementById(id)) return;"

It should look like this:

```
FB = null;
(function(d, s, id) { 
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    //if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/pt_BR/all.js#xfbml=1";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

Comment: It works for me now :) Maybe I did it wrong the first time. Thanks a lot! Now I can get rid of the iframe widget

Comment: Please make sure that <div id="fb-root"></div> is inside the partial loaded by ng-view, otherwise I had problems getting it working.

Comment: IMO, this might work for some cases but it's not universal answer. Why? for embedded videos, it incorrectly calculates width-height and your video would exist but it won't be visible due to 0px height/width. https://stackoverflow.com/a/50435097/3241111

Comment: FB = null just resets the facebook script. That is not optimal because it reloads the whole facebook js once again while it only has to force facebook to reprocess the dom tree. The correct answer is below, you have to just add if (window.FB) window.FB.XFBML.parse().

Answer (score 8):

The accepted answer given by user2912405 it's perfect.
I just wanted to add that if you are using AngularJS

You should use:

```
$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {
    (function(d, s, id) {
        FB = null;
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        //if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=204269043065238";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
      }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
});
```

To get the buttons re-loaded every time we change the view, for example when we follow a link

Comment: When I add more items by AngularJS (ng-Repeat), The facebook like button (html5) won't work... Any way to run the init again?

Comment: You mean you have one like button for every item in the ng-repeat?

Comment: I got an error when using this. It's "Error: assignment to undeclared variable FB". How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

accepted answer worked for me, after much trial an error (fb root was ommitted). here is the full snippet to include in your view:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
    FB=null;
    (function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&appId=xxxxxxxxx&version=v2.0";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

also make sure to delete any code from index page

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer did not work for me on my Angular 5 project.

Adding this to my component class worked:

```
ngOnInit() {
    if (window['FB']) {
        window['FB'].XFBML.parse();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I ended up with something like this. I have a component in angular 1.5. In index file, there is classic markup from documentation and inside the component

```
this.$onInit = function() {
    var facebookButtonEl = $element[0].querySelector('.fb-share-button');

    if (facebookButtonEl)
    angular.element(facebookButtonEl)
        .attr('href', $location.absUrl())
        .attr('data-href', $location.absUrl());

    if (window.FB) {
        window.FB.XFBML.parse();
    }
}
```

The important part is the FB.XFBML.parse() which envokes re-rendering of the button

Comment: This works but for some reason angular is telling me that XFBML is undefined Any ideas why this is or how I can stop the error message?

Comment: Nevermind I added the window.FB and it worked completely

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, the accepted answer is not good answer. Following reasons:

- You would end up inserting script multiple times.
- `window.FB = null` is better syntax, instead of `FB = null`
- If script already exists then don't add-fetch script again. Instead, manually do `window.FB.XFBML.parse();`.

  ```
  (function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) {
         window.FB.XFBML.parse(); // Helps to identify FB elements again.
         return;
      }
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;


      js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.6"; // Put your Latest version here.
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
  ```

[FB.XFBML.parse](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse/)

Answer (score 0):

For those using opt-in cookie consent (for GDPR Law for example) and need to active for the first time programmatically the fb plugin:

```
var loadFB = (function (d, s, id) {
  //- call this function after receiving consent
  return function loadFB() {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (window['FB']) {
      window['FB'].XFBML.parse();
      return;
    }

    js = d.createElement(s);
    js.id = id;
    js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/fr_FR/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v3.0';
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

In app.component.ts :

```
const onNavigationEnd = this.router.events.pipe(
  filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
  map((event: NavigationEnd) => {
    // ccService is the cookieConsentService
    if (this.ccService.hasConsented()) {

      // Set Google Analytics
      ga('set', 'page', event.urlAfterRedirects);
      ga('send', 'pageview');

      // Set Facebook sdk
      loadFB();

    }
  })
);
```